# Tomcat .war deployment and rollback

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I have a `ROOT.war` file which I used to deploy version 1 of my web site. I now rename this file to be `ROOT_v1.war` and set it aside. Then I do some changes and create a new `ROOT.war` file and deploy it.

If I want to do a rollback, will it be enough to just rename and copy `ROOT_v1.war` back to the server?

Or do I need to update its date? Or do the dates that count are those of the files inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if I update (Touch) the date of the old .war file to be current It is enough  to make it redeploy over the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, I would undeploy the application, check my tomcat/webapps/ folder for any traces of the application having been left & then deploy the 'original' application.

Comment: How do you "undeploy" an application ?

Comment: Either click 'undeploy' in the manager webapp interface or `rm tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war`

Comment: "the manager webapp interface" ? where do I find this ?

Comment: If installed & running It will probably be at `ipaddress:port/manager` but then requires a password etc. I'm guessing you haven't got any of that sorted though, so just `rm` or `mv` the war.

Comment: /manager does not seem to exist on my installation.
where would I install this from? (please on both linux and windows).

Comment: See my comment Jul 14 8:05 - "or `rm tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war`".

Comment: actually I did not try an rm because I found the touch solution. but rm would definitely be better as it does not change the times on my files. I will try it next time.

Comment: b.t.w - what happens during the time between when I rm the .war on the server and upload the old/new .war ?  will the old version still be avaliable ?

Comment: No, when you `rm` the file (or `mv` if you've no other copy) the app will be undeployed and unavailable.

Comment: since my upload takes about 5 min, I guess it would be better if I upload to another folder and then `rm` and `mv` the new file to minimize downtime... Do I have to wait between those two actions? for the app to be properly undeployed?

Comment: Check out https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough. In my experience it doesn't always work like that. You should always test to be sure.

If you want to be 100% sure, stop tomcat, delete the cache. If you have multiple apps running, or if you cannot stop tomcat for some reason, you might want to try the admin-module, which lets you stop the specific webapp. Then you can delete the cache for that app, and start it again. If you know what has changed, you can look for the subdirectories where the changes have been made, and only delete those directories in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming ROOT_v1.war to ROOT.war would deploy application successfully. You'll need to restart tomcat though.

Comment: its been my experience that this is NOT enough.